# Are there any tools for visualizing Git commits?

Tags: git

I’d like to be able to write better questions on using Git, but I’m finding it difficult to do so without the ability to show a relevant commit history.  In most cases I don’t even have a repository representing of what I want to show, but I know what I *want* to show.

Is there some sort of tool that will help me build a visual representation?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to your goal. Is there a reason you cannot create a repository in the state you want to represent? That seems like it would be the best approach. Otherwise, maybe look at a generic diagram/graph solution such as Graphviz, LaTeX+TikZ, Microsoft Visio, etc.

Comment: Create a repository that does what you want.  i often find myself doing things like `git init; for i in a b c d; to date > $i; git add $i; git commit -m "Add $i"; done`, and making throw away branches to create the desired structure.  Often, the exercise of creating a repo that recreates the state you want is a great exercise that answers your questions for you.

Comment: Do you mean `gitk`?

Answer (score 0):

I use smartgit to commit and push my commits, there I can also see my commit history to the specified project and branch.

Comment: I think the question author is after something to produce ASCII-art diagrams of commit sequences, like the Git documentation.